# Detect disconnect/loss of hardware components (Windows 7)

Tags: winapi, windows-7, usb

**Scenario:** A critical computer system is operator-controlled via standard USB keyboard and mouse. Also, there is a DVI-monitor connected to view the operator-targeted GUI. The computer system runs a soft-PLC system based on Windows 7 Professional or, alternatively, Windows Embedded Standard 7 (the "system software").

**Question:** Is there a software solution, to detect the loss (disconnect/failure) of USB HID-devices such as the keyboard or mouse, and the single DVI-display? This is important, since the critical system can no longer be expected to function properly, without the operator able to manipulate it or see displayed content.

**Own considerations:** This likely requires low-level WINAPI calls, which is fine. I am thinking that a windows service might be constantly seeking to enumerate the number of keyboards and displays - perhaps even identify them via model or serial number. If this enumeration and/or identification reaches zero or fails entirely, the system-software must of course react fast and appropriately (i.e. go to fail-mode or similar).

As far as I see it, this is general issue with all critical operator-controlled systems. Question is then: Is there already software or hardware for this in existence perhaps?

**Note:** Operator is always human.

Comment: Will [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+RegisterDeviceNotification) not work?

Comment: @Dúthomhas I don't know :) Will it? I have never worked with WINAPI calls before (including windows services). But it seems to be relevant. You are very welcome to expand with an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/Brandon-T/HDMI I use `RegisterDeviceNotification` to detect when an HDMI Cable connected to a TV or Monitor is plugged in and unplugged. Slight modification to the GUUID to detect USB and other devices.

Comment: I think you are unrealistic in hoping to solve this without a programmer who is a Win32 expert.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, that may be true, although I can do magic myself given enough time and resources :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, as for an answer this isn’t going to be much more than a “read the docs” plus some links... Sorry.

First, MSDN documentation.

- [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+RegisterDeviceNotification)
- [Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+Detecting+Media+Insertion+or+Removal+Windows)
- [Talking to USB devices, start to finish (Windows Store app)](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+Talking+to+USB+devices+start+to+finish+Windows+Store+app)

I found a C# class on CodeProject.com that does this; the accompanying article is pretty good.

- [Detecting USB Drive Removal in a C# Program](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program).

I admit that the last time I did anything like this was some years ago, and only for CD notifications. I’ve since lost the code (both my primary and backup hard drives failed within days of each other, LOL).

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, except, it doesn't even provide links to the actual targets. See [answer], in particular: *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: Will this method of registering for device notifications, be able to pool continuously for an enumeration/list of devices of a specific class? The notification-handler seems to only be called when a device-event occurs (e.g. removal/insertion of USB-device). Is this correctly understood?

Comment: Yes, you are registering for a notification event.